# How To bind input type time with C# property and fetch value after the change has changed

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, maui, .net-maui

I am not able to fetch the value or change the value of input type time when I am binding with the c# property.

```
<input type="time" class="form-control" @bind="EndTime" @bind:format="HH:mm">
```

**C#Property**

```
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
```

How to bind that property if the EndTime already contains value then it will show that and if the Value change then the EndTime value will change.

Comment: Try without `@bind:format="HH:mm"`

Answer (score 0):

When you set the input value to say "12:30", this is no longer a valid date format (there's no date!), so Blazor can't save it back to `EndTime`.  You set it, Blazor tries to update the field and fails, and the value is set back to the current valid value,

If you only want a Time property then use `TimeOnly` and set the input type to `time` and it will work correctly.

Remember, the actual formatting of Date/Time is controlled by the browser and the locale settings.

Here's my test page:

```cs
@page "/"

<h3>Date Time Testing</h3>

<div class="m-2">
    <input class="form-control" type="time" @bind=model.Time />
</div>
<div class="m-2">
    <input class="form-control" type="date" @bind=model.Date />
</div>
<div class="m-2">
    <input class="form-control" type="time" @bind=model.DateAndTime @bind:format="hh:mm" />
</div>
<div class="m-2">
    Time : @model.Time.ToLongTimeString()
</div>
<div class="m-2">
    Date : @model.Date.ToLongDateString()
</div>
<div class="m-2">
    DateTime : @model.DateAndTime.ToString()
</div>
@code {
    private ModelData model = new ModelData();

    public class ModelData
    {
        public TimeOnly Time { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; }
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```